# How to make a context menu for iframe to save images?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, contextmenu

I have a iFrame in my web page, that visits different websites each time. Such as Facebook, Google Plus etc.

How can I make custom context menu for saving image from those sites within my iFrame? That means the iFrame context menu item should have "save image" option, which will be only visble when user right clicks on an image inside the iFrame.

Comment: Please explain your problem a little bit further, as far as I understand this is something that can already be done with or without an iframe without having to do any code.

Comment: Ok. I want to make a web browser using iframe for firefox os. Inside that iframe i have to make a context menu option for saving images. Firefox os has allready given an api reference for creating context menu in iframe. But i dont know how to use thoae api for having context manu with "save image" option.

Comment: Unfortunately I am not familiar with Firefox OS, I do however recommend that you modify the post and add some tags and information about your specific request so that you'll get a faster solution :)

Comment: Ok. But isn't there any solution for making a auto image detecting context menu for iframe whithout using any api.